# Nothing displaying for Drupal main menu

Tags: theming, routes

I'm trying to output the `main_menu` in to a custom theme on the `page.tpl.php` template however nothing is displaying when I add `<?php print theme("links", $main_menu) ?>`

However when I do a `var_dump` on the `$main_menu` I get

`array(2) { ["menu-218"]=> array(2) { ["href"]=> string(7) "" ["title"]=> string(4) "Home" } ["menu-335"]=> array(2) { ["href"]=> string(6) "node/1" ["title"]=> string(4) "Home" } }`

What might I be doing wrong? I'm new to Drupal so be kind please :D

I do have `features[] = main_menu` in my .info file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following lines to your template file. Works for me.

```
$main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu'));
print drupal_render($main_menu_tree);
```

Comment: Still no result unfortunately, do I need to put this in a function in the template file?

Comment: yes, in your theme's `page.tpl.php`, wherever you need to print (generally inside `<div id='header-menu><?php //copy above code here ?> </div>`. Make sure you clear your cache after this.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood you when you said template file, I thought the `template.php` file :P

Thats worked great thanks! How do I add custom attributes to this though so I may style it?

Comment: There is a `id` to the `div` already; you can add a `class` as well by something like `<div id='header-menu' class='header-menu-class'>....`

Comment: I see, but what if I needed to edit any attributes in the outputted list HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that from theme. But, there's an [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module which does exactly the same!

Comment: Ok :) thanks for your help, I know I'll be here a fair few more times in the near future!

Comment: You're welcome :) Drupal community will always welcome you :) happy learning!

Comment: Sorry to open this back up again but I've come to create a new menu and replaced `main-menu` with `site-menu` and nothing is showing, any ideas?

Comment: @jonathandey Try `menu-site-menu`, custom menu names are usually prefixed with `menu-`